# It's my friend.. again

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle, steganography

Yet again, my friend is back at it!

Just today, I asked him for something, and he sent me a blank image, though I have a certain feeling it's not blank.

You guys helped the last time, but can you help me again?
Here's the image.[image]

See?
Entirely blank.

Direct link for those interested: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE2be.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image in the question contains

> A link that's not quite white - flood filling with another color reveals: [`https://jsfiddle.net/od7c3cra`](https://jsfiddle.net/od7c3cra)

This link has an image and text. The image depicts the word

> `WEST`

using that word as

> a Vigenere key on the text

gives us another

> link, this time to: [`http://b.reich.io/qovspa.png`](http://b.reich.io/qovspa.png)

this is

> binary; white = 0, black = 1, gray is a separator

this translation yields

> `01111001 01101111 01110101 00100000 01110111 01101001 01101110 00101110`

which of course says

> `you win.`

Comment: Good job! You did it very fast.

Answer (score 3):

> There's light-gray-on-white text hidden in the upper corner, saying "https://jsfiddle.net/od7c3cra/". That link leads to an arrow pointing west, and the encrypted URL x.vwbyl.ah/msnlle.hgc ...

Ah, I've been beaten to the punch. Alas. Nice puzzle though.